Getting WinEdt to remember recent documents
I have been using WinEdt with MiKTeX for about 20 years, through many, many installs on many different Windows machines.  Through it all I have kept my TeX files in the same folder under Documents.  In the past when I would install (or, re-install)  WinEdt and MiKTeX on a machine, then when I first opened a TeX file I would have to direct WinEdt to my file folder, and after that WinEdt would automatically go to that folder.   And WinEdt kept an accurate log of "recent documents," which was often convenient for me to use.
My current install works fine (on two Windows machines) except that every time I start WinEdt it claims I have no recent documents.  And when I try to open a document WinEdt looks for it in WinEdtTeam > WinEdt 11, where it finds nothing.  I can direct WinEdt to the correct folder, in the routine way, but I have to do this every time I restart WinEdt and it is really boring.
Reinstalling WinEdt several times made no difference.  I did some as admin which I always used to do, and some as individual user.
Is there a way I can get WinEdt to start keeping accurate track of my recent documents?
